# odometry for ardrone

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, ardrone-autonomy, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.
I started programming the ardrone using ROS (I'm a newbie to both) and i wanted to implement a basic form of odometry of the kind px = px + (vxcos(...) - vysin(...)), py = ..., using the speed information provided from the navdata. Unfortunately, in this way a lot of error is introduced. Since i've never used ROS, i wanted to know if there is a better way to do this, i mean, if ROS offers a way to keep track of the position of the drone.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56429/odometry-for-ardrone/) by [jacky_90](https://answers.ros.org/users/4309/jacky_90/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Jacky!

you could test one of our odometer wrappers, [viso2_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/viso2_ros) (wrapper of libviso2) or [fovis_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fovis_ros) (wrapper or fovis).

There is also several people working on [PTAM](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ptam) for ardrone and various quadcopters.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally ros returns odometry but not for ardrone. For quadcoptors odometry readings are not easily estimated unlike in the case of mobile robots. To estimate the position either you can integrate velocity values that u get in navdata but as you mentioned it is very erroneous . One way to estimate position of Drone is using Ar tags. You can either put a artag on drone and let some external camera track its location or you can put artags at predefined location and let ardrone camera see it and then estimate its position. For artags look ar_pose package in ROS.

Another way is to implement VSLAM using monocular camera like PTAM.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2